# api not working when in production with nginx

Tags: angular, laravel, nginx, deployment, devops

I'm trying to put my full-stack application (Angular and Laravel) in production, so i decided to use a remote server running nginx as a reverse-proxy.

I proceeded as follows:

1. I built the angular front-end with `ng build` and moved the content of the list folder inside the directory i defined as root in my sites configuration
2. I copied the whole laravel application and putted the content inside the root i defined inside my sites configuration
3. I made this file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and then symlinked it

```
server {
    include mime.types; 
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/myForum/forum-frontend/public;
    index index.html;

    server_name 207.154.202.138;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        root /var/www/html/myForum/forum-api/public;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

4. restarted the nginx server

Problem is that when i go to my server ip address every call the front-end makes to `/api` returns `text/html` instead of `application/json`

I also noticed that ifi try to add /api to the address the application redirects me to the angular frontend.

What am i doing wrong, is there any other material i should provide?

Comment: One issue I see is that you have defined the root for the /api location to be /var/www/html/myForum/forum-api/public, but you are also using proxy_pass to send requests to http://localhost:8001. It's unclear what is running on port 8001